# Controller calling twice while using reload in $state.go() ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a url router like this

```
.state('app.newObservation', {
//cache:true,
url: "/newObservation",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/newObservation.html",
    controller: 'NewObservationCtrl'
  }
 }
})
```

In different controller I'm writing like this, which on click calls `goToNewObs()` function.

```
appne.controller('LogoutController', function($scope, $state) {

  $scope.goToNewObs = function(){
   $state.go("app.newObservation",null,{reload:true});
  }
})
```

I'm giving a button which redirects me to `newObservation.html` ... But here the `NewObservationCtrl` is calling twice.

I didn't included any controller in `newObservation.html` ... even though it is calling twice...

What is the mistake I'm doing here?

Comment: could you try to replicate in the plunkr??

Comment: @Pankaj , Actually it is a big project and I don't know how to create it, sorry...Actually for the first time as there is no cache it is executing twice, after that it is executing once..

Comment: I cant give cache:false in url routing because of my dependencies in project.

Comment: We would really need some more information, what does your template looks like, and your Controller, etc. a plunk would really help with this.

Comment: Is your `NewObservationCtrl` mentioned twice, might be it is been there in one on parent state

Comment: No @pankaj. I checked it twice.. It is only included once

Comment: I made a plunker but controller is executing only once in that, but in my code it is executing twice. My code is in github can you please take a look at that.[Github code](https://github.com/ifpindia/biodiv-ionic/tree/master/www) .

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this code,

```
$ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function(){ 
      $state.go('app.newObservation');
    })
```